# Concurrent futures - make one worker do different task

Tags: python, parallel-processing, jira-rest-api

I'm using `ThreadPoolExecutor` from `concurrent.futures` package to fetch data from JIRA. I have to fetch a lot of data and to not DDOS the website by logging to JIRA for each request I implemented the `Session` class that uses `cookie-based authentication`, so instead of logging each time, I log once at the start of fetching process, get the cookie and using that cookie I'm sending requests to the JIRA. Unfortunately cookie is valid only for 5 minutes, therefore after those 5 minutes I need to retrieve new cookie.

The problem is that all workers work on similar pace and after exactly 5 minutes most of them will be "ready" approximately at the same time. Therefore most of them will get to `if time.time() - cookie_time > 300` at the same moment (before `cookie_time` was updated by any of them) and most of them will execute the code in `if statement`. The outcome of that will be that `x` workers will log to JIRA causing `x` logins and may result in ban for some time.

```
import concurrent.futures as fs
import time

cookie = get_cookie()
cookie_time = time.time()

page_size = 1000
total_num_issues = 100000

with fs.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=30) as ex:
    for start_at in range(0, total_num_issues + 1, page_size):
         # check if cookie has already expired (300s = 5mins)
         if time.time() - cookie_time > 300
              cookie = get_cookie()
              cookie_time = time.time()    
         extra_params = {"startAt": start_at, "maxResults": page_size}
         future_list.append(ex.submit(send_request, url, session, {**extra_params}))
    for future in fs.as_completed(future_list):
         issues += future.result()["issues"]
```

So my question is: is it possible to assign one worker to perform only given tasks (execute `get_cookie()`), while the others will do the rest?

I did not share `send_request` and `get_cookie` functions to not overcomplicate the question but their way of working is kinda straightforward.

Some clarification:

```
During init lets say `cookie_time = 0`
After 300s `If statement` is true
Worker_1 gets to `If` at 300.0001 and updates `cookie_time` at 300.00012
Worker_2 gets to `If` at 300.0004 (after Worker_1, but before update) -> updates `cookie_time` at 300.0015
Worker_3 gets to `If` at 300.0011 (just before Worker_1s update) and updates at 300.0025
Worker_4 gets to `If` at 300.0013 (so after Worker_1 update, new cookie is valid)
```

So we got 3 logins instead of 1

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the cookie expiry check to the `send_request` function. The code that queues up the functions to run happens before any of them actually run, so the `time.time() - cookie_time > 300` check will always* be `False`.

What you can do is add a shared state to the threads, something along the lines of this:

```py
class CookieState:
    def __init__(self, valid_duration):
        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.valid_duration = valid_duration
    
    def is_valid(self):
        return time.time() - self.start_time < self.valid_duration
```

Then instantiate a CookieState before running the `start_at` loop and pass it to the `ex.submit` call so all the `send_request` calls share a single `CookieState` instance. Then you need to add code to the cookie state to get a new valid cookie and reset the timer. You'll probably need to use `await` so that the queued-up tasks wait for the new cookie.

*unless it takes more than 300 seconds to submit the tasks, which seems extremely unlikely.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was trying to put `get_cookie` inside `send_request` but it did not help (because `Some clarification` in my question I added after your response). But maybe if I add `await` as you mentioned it will work, so I will give it a try!